# react-select defaultValue not loading from State

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to set the default value for my `react-select`, but it is not working properly.

`import Select from 'react-select';`

I have the state for the selected properties

```
const [ selectedProps, setSelectedProps ] = useState([]);
```

In my useEffect, I set the value coming from the props

```
setSelectedProps(props.location.user.properties);
```

Right before rendering the component, I log the data to make sure that is correct

```
console.log(properties);
console.log(selectedProps);
```

Here is my select

```
<Select
    defaultValue={selectedProps}
    isMulti
    name="properties"
    options={properties}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    onChange={handleChangeProperties}
/>
```

The defaultValue is not showing anything.

The log, at first both `properties` and `selectedProps` are empty. Then, the second log it has values:
Properties:

```
[
   (3) […]
​
0: Object { value: 2618, label: "Prop 1" }
​
1: Object { value: 2309, label: "Prop 2" }
​
2: Object { value: 2192, label: "Prop 3" }
​​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

selectedProps:

```
[
  {
    "value": 2618,
    "label": "Prop 1"
  },
  {
    "value": 2192,
    "label": "Prop 3"
  }
]
```

If I hard code he defaultValue it works, but not with the data coming from the variable.

Comment: why are you using `useEffect`? can't you do `useState(props.location.user.properties)`?

Comment: I initiate the state as empty and the useEffect set the state data if the ```props.location.user``` is defined. Otherwise, I redirect the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, you could assign the initial state when declaring it  [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-merkle-7l5ys?file=/src/select.js)